# ¿Cómo mostrar las notificaciones push en sitio web?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, firebase-messaging

Desarrollo una aplicación Web y necesitó mostrar notificaciones push usando firebase ya escribí el código que la envía  a la DB y el q la exporta desde la DB, ahora solo falta que en mi sitio se muestre la notificación push.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Código que envía:

```
function SendNotify() {
    const txt = document.getElementById('msj');
    var notificationMessage = txt.value;

    if (!notificationMessage) return false;

    database.ref('/notifications')
        .push({
            user: auth.currentUser.displayName,
            message: notificationMessage,
            userProfileImg: auth.currentUser.photoURL,
            date: date
        })
        .then(() => {
            document.getElementById('msj').value = '';
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log("error enviando");
        });

    txt.value = '';   
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo que exporta:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.Notifications = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{notificationId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const user = await snap.val().user;
        const message = await snap.val().message;
        const userProfileImg = await snap.val().userProfileImg;
        const date = await snap.val().date;

        // Notification details.
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: `Test SocialWifi de: ${user}`,
                body: `Hoy: ${date} , Nuevo Mensaje  ${message}`,
                icons: `${userProfileImg}`,
                click_action: 'https://sudokudetodos.com'
            }
        };

        console.info(payload);

    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este articulo puede serte de ayuda: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hize fue agregar codigo a el archivo index.js  de la carpeta functions que se crea durante el deploy de firebase ...

Codigo completo :

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.Notifications = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{notificationId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

        const user = await snap.val().user;
        const message = await snap.val().message;
        const userProfileImg = await snap.val().userProfileImg;
        const date = await snap.val().date;

        // Notification details.
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: `SocialWifi de: ${user}`,
                body: ` ${message} Hoy: ${date}`,
                icons: `${userProfileImg}`,
                image: "http://www.icons101.com/icons/5/Replacement_Icons_by_creatiVe5/128/Telegram.png",
                click_action: 'https://sudokudetodos.com'
            }
        };

        console.info(payload);

        // Clean invalid tokens
        function cleanInvalidTokens(tokensWithKey, results) {

            const invalidTokens = [];

            results.forEach((result, i) => {
                if (!result.error) return false;

                console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokensWithKey[i].token, result.error);

                switch (result.error.code) {
                    case "messaging/invalid-registration-token":
                    case "messaging/registration-token-not-registered":
                        invalidTokens.push(admin.database().ref('/tokens').child(tokensWithKey[i].key).remove());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });

            return Promise.all(invalidTokens);
        }



        return admin.database().ref('/tokens').once('value').then((data) => {

            if (!data.val()) return;

            const snapshot = data.val();
            const tokensWithKey = [];
            const tokens = [];

            for (let key in snapshot) {
                tokens.push(snapshot[key].token);
                tokensWithKey.push({
                    token: snapshot[key].token,
                    key: key
                });
            }

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);

        });

    });
```